# How to split eth_senduseroperation method by eth_sendRawTransaction method

Tags: web3js, transactions

I want to take the parameters out of the eth_Senduseroperation method to generate the data value, use the eth_RawTransaction method to generate the rawTransaction value, and finally send it up the chain via the eth_SendnRawTransaction meth